# Passing a Binary Search Tree between forms

Tags: c#, winforms, binary-search-tree

I'm currently trying to access a binary search tree I created in form1 within form2. My code for the first form is:

```
public Home() {
    InitializeComponent();
}

AddArtist secondForm = new AddArtist();
BSTree<Artist> ArtistCollection = new BSTree<Artist>();

private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    secondForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

The code for my second form is:

```
private void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string artistName = txtName.Text;

    Artist newArtist = new Artist(artistName);
    ArtistCollection.InsertItem(artistName);

    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

I've tried the method of declaring it within its own class so no results.

Answer (score 1):

Just expose `ArtistCollection` as a property in your first form.

```
public BSTree<Artist> ArtistCollection { get; set; }
```

You can then refer to it from your second form like this:

```
var tree = form1.ArtistCollection;
```

Or, create a new constructor in Form2

```
public Form2(BSTree<Artist> artistCollection)
{
    this.artistCollection = artistCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when instantiating the second form they must first pass with "this" with which they must deal with in the constructor of the second form